# ssh-agent: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: bash, ssh, archlinux

I have done a ton of research already, but none of those works.
This is output from my terminal:

```
$ ps aux | grep ssh-agent
tsiruan   4080  0.0  0.0  13468   388 ?        Ss   11:47   0:00 ssh-agent
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-8CJH68abyLAa/agent.4079
SSH_AGENT_PID=4080
$ sudo ssh-add .ssh/bitbucket_ssh
[sudo] password for tsiruan:
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I have tried `$ eval $(ssh-agent)` with backticks, single quote, double quote, with and without parentheses, with and without -s option, and even some answers like:

```
$ exec ssh-agent bash
```

please help me , I am running bash on arch linux.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about *writing software*. Consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for questions about using tools that shipped with your system.

Comment: that said, the big problem here is that you're using `sudo` to run `ssh-add`. When you run `sudo`, that makes your command run as a different user, with a different environment (so it no longer has your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`). This is the same problem asked on Unix.SE [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249639/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent).

Comment: BTW -- using `sudo` on commands where you shouldn't have to use `sudo` often creates permission problems that force you to use `sudo` again later (when you otherwise wouldn't need it). It's a tool that should only be used when you have a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### First Choice: Don't Use `sudo`

```
ssh-add .ssh/bitbucket_ssh
```

#### Second Choice: Pass The Environment Variable Explicitly

Assuming your `bitbucket_ssh` file is only readable by root -- the more appropriate approach is to fix the permissions, but as an interim approach, you can pass `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` through:

```
sudo env SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ssh-add .ssh/bitbucket_ssh
```

Comment: Community Wiki since this is answering a known-off-topic question.